# SOQL Query on UserType encountering issues with local language

Tags: apex, soql, user, language

I was wondering if somebody would be able to assist with an issue I am encountering with my SOQL query. 
A user changed his local language to Dutch and now one of my SOQL queries is not returning the required information. I have found that this is due to the word 'standard' in English is 'standaard' in Dutch. 
I contact Salesforce support for assistance and they have declared that there is no way to query for a non localized user types.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT Id,IsActive,FirstName,LastName,Name,UserRole.Name,Title,Profile.Name,UserType 
FROM user 
WHERE IsActive = true 
    AND (FirstName like '%' OR FirstName = null) 
    AND (LastName like '%' OR LastName = null) 
    AND (UserRole.Name like '%' OR UserRole.Name = null) 
    AND (Profile.Name like '%' OR Profile.Name = null) 
    AND UserType like 'Standard%'
ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 201
```

I am searching by standard as I wish to avoid searching for portal users.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
After a lot of emails back and forth and a remote session, Salesforce have acknowledged that this is a bug on their side. They have added this to 'Known Issues' so if people could click on 'This Issue Affects me', that would be fantastic!
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XUPAA2

Best Regards,

Kevin

Comment: I'm not aware of how translation works in salesforce, but shouldn't it only be visual? With other words: shouldn't you only change the text that's shown to the user and not variable names/types/anything else?

Comment: Hi Novarg, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this query requires the text to be translated to the user's language. For example, if I wish for the above query to return any data while the user is using the Dutch language then the second last line must be AND UserType like 'Standaard%'.
This is not ideal as it will require having the translation for standard in all languages and we will have to adapt our code etc.

Comment: can you make a global variable which will contain all translations for *Standard* in all languages that you use? For example a set of strings. Then you could change that second last line to `AND UserType IN :yourGlobalVariable`

Comment: Hi Novarg, thank you for the the recommendation. We are going to implement something similar as a quick hack for the moment and hopefully Salesforce will fix the overall issue soon which is a part of their 'Known Issues'. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XUPAA2

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce inadvertently solved our issue. I changed the operator from being 'like' to '=' and changed 'Standard%' to 'Standard' and have found that it works with every language.
The updated SOQL query is:

> SELECT Id,IsActive,FirstName,LastName,Name,UserRole.Name,Title,Profile.Name,UserType 
>   FROM user 
>   WHERE IsActive = true 
>     AND (FirstName like '%' OR FirstName = null) 
>     AND (LastName like '%' OR LastName = null) 
>     AND (UserRole.Name like '%' OR UserRole.Name = null) 
>     AND (Profile.Name like '%' OR Profile.Name = null) 
>     AND UserType = 'Standard'
>   ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 201